# sml error inserting EQUALOP

Tags: sml

I'm writing a function in sml using emacs and when I try to compile this code

```
fun tryDivide small n =
if n = 1 then true
else if ((small mod n) = 0) then tryDivide small (n-1)
else false

fun lcmHelper small div =
if tryDivide (small div) = false then lcmHelper ((small+div) div)
else small

(*Start by calling this*)
fun lcm d = 
val small = d
lcmHelper (small d)
```

It is supposed to find the lowest value that can be divided by d (fun lcm d)
I am pretty sure that the algorithm works, but there are syntax errors.

At the start of the "fun lcm d =" I get an error that says "Error Inserting EQUALOP"

Any ideas what might be causing this?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

```
fun lcm d =
  let 
    val small = d 
  in
    lcmHelper (small d)
  end
```

Comment: They have a syntax error.  This fixes it.  let val = ... in ... end, not val = ...

Comment: Thank, yeah that fixes the problem with the equalop. Sadly there seems to be something else wrong. Now it complains about the lcmHelper function: "Error: right hand side of clause doesn't agree with function result type [tycon mismatch]
expression _->_->int
result _->int

Comment: It seems lcmHelper has a host of problems.  `small + div` implies small and div are ints (barring overloading).  Thus, there's a type error in the expression `(small div)` which is trying to apply small to div.  I'd start by fixing that.  It's generally helpful to write the types when you're learning sml.  e.g. fun lcmHelper (small: int) (dev:int): int = ...